# 1and1 domain to my heroku app

Tags: heroku, dns, subdomain

I'm trying to make my fresh new domain point to my heroku app, and i don't know if i made everything right. Could you help me out ?

[image: base domain]

[image]

[image]

[image]

1st screenshot : 1and1 base domain configuration

2nd screenshot : 1and1 www subdomain overview

3rd screenshot : 1and1 www subdomain's cname configuration

4th screenshot : heroku domain configuration

And if i go to mydomain.com or www.mydomain.com, it stills point to 1and1 default page. Did i do everything right or do i have to wait until redirection is done ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need also to forward all requests from your root domain:

yourdomain.com -> www.yourdomain.com